# Hide first columns in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm writing a mode to more easily deal with some logfiles I have.  The first several columns are all the same metadata, and I would like to omit this from being displayed.  What's the best way of hiding this information - going through each line and marking that section of each line with the `invisible text-property?

These logfiles will be just displayed, not edited

Comment: Are you just displaying the logfiles or do you want to edit them?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `.emacs`:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\[.*\\]" (0 '(face default display "meta") append))) t)
  (push 'display font-lock-extra-managed-props)))
```

This will display your metadata which is matched using a regexp `"\\[.*\\]"` as `meta`

```
[01/01/2012 14:00 - Message] Hello World!
```

Will temporarily become

```
meta Hello World!
```

Just replace the regexp with one that'll match your metadata.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you advice me about what would you write if the meta tag was in xml tag format? I have put a question for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246503/regex-for-identifying-all-xml-tags-in-elisp. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'd try to use a font-lock-keyword that adds the `invisible' property.  Something like the 100% guaranteed untested code below:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil
  '(("^.............." (0 '(face nil invisible t)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to write an elisp function that reads each line of the log and discards the information that you do not want before printing it.

Comment: Not quite what I was hoping - specifically, I want this to still be in an emacs buffer, so i can navigate around it as normal.

Comment: This is the approach taken in magit for example. Git functions are called, their outputs are parsed, some information is discarded and some is displayed.

Comment: If the files are big and/or change often, generating copious amounts of temporary data is not very scalable.  Unfortunately, my impression is that that may nevertheless be the way to go here.  But my Emacs knowledge is not entirely current.

Comment: This is a log file, so, everytime a new line becomes available, it just needs to be stripped off of the redundant information and then put in the buffer/displayed.